# How can I find state-level data on the unemployment rate of youth for 2014 and 2015?

Tags: data-request, unemployment, empirical-evidence, minimum-wage, paneldata

I have found state-level, monthly unemployment data for 2014/2015, and I have found *national* monthly youth unemployment data for 2014/2015. However, I need all four together; *State-level*, *monthly* *youth* unemployment data for *2014 and 2015*. In addition to scouring their website, I have called the Bureau of Labor Statistics and they were not helpful, unfortunately. 
Alternatively, state-level monthly unemployment data on low-wage earners for 2014/2015 would work as well. 
Basically, I want to find the effects of the state-level minimum wage changes occurring on January 2015, and these affect primarily youth and other low-wage earners.
Actually, if I could find this data at the yearly level for 2014 and 2015 instead of the monthly level, that wouldn't be too bad. It wouldn't be quite as useful as monthly, but I could still run the regression and get some results. The other elements are pretty crucial though.
Thanks!!

Comment: What did they say at BLS when you called them?

Comment: About the monthly data, they said that such specific data was not collected  monthly by the BLS. At the yearly level, they said it would not be published until 2016. The person I talked to sounded new and uncertain. Of course, he may have been correct about both of these things, but I am not ready to give up yet haha.

Comment: I know that unemployment data may be embargoed until a certain date and time so they may not be allowed to give them to you even if they have the data